# How to enable "too-many-locals" Pylint message in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I cleaned up my code so that it passed linting in Visual Studio Code with the following settings:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
```

Then I ran `pylint` directly and imagine my surprise when several new messages of a type "*too-many-*" popped up that I then accounted for in my source file with:

```py
# pylint: disable=too-many-arguments,too-many-locals,too-many-branches
```

I headed over to the [Linting Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) documentation and read that some specific things are still enabled/disabled. My question then is: how do I get Visual Studio Code to use Pylint the same as if it's running with *no arguments* and therefore enable messages like these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [too-many-locals](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:r0914) PyLint message is under the category ["Refactor (R)"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint), which by default, is set to be displayed as a "*Hint (light bulbs)*" only. It is *still* enabled but hints are not shown in the Problems panel (or on any Error/Warning indicator that I know of), only in the code as a tooltip:

[image]
[image]

If you want to also show them in the Problems panel, in addition to this:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
```

you can also configure the `python.linting.pylintCategorySeverity.xxx` settings. For example, for "too-many-locals", change `refactor` from `"Hint"` to `"Warning"`:

```
"python.linting.pylintCategorySeverity.refactor": "Warning",
```

Alternatively, from the Settings UI:

[image]

Once you've changed it to Error or Warning, it will now appear in the Problems panel along with all other Refactor types:

[image]

You can do the same for all the other PyLint categories.

Comment: Thanks, the `"python.linting.pylintCategorySeverity.refactor": "Warning",` is what did it. I already had the other Pylint settings but changing the severity is what I needed to do.